# (Python) Check Word Count in a File and then congratulate you if you've hit a certain Number of Words daily

Tags: python, calendar, word-count

I tried writing something where Python checks a file's number of words yesterday and the file's words today. Then it compares the values of both with each other and gives you a message according to how much you wrote since yesterday.

But it seems to save the same word count value in both yesterday and today.

```
import datetime

today = datetime.date.today()
yesterday = datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=-1)

if yesterday:
    file = open("python_test.txt", "r")
    read_data = file.read()
    per_word = read_data.split()
    y = len(per_word)
    if today:
        file = open("python_test.txt", "r")
        read_data = file.read()
        per_word = read_data.split()
        x = len(per_word)
        if x > y:
            print("Good job! You wrote a lot!")
        else:
            print("You should try to keep up!")
```

Any idea on how to fix that or how to optimize the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `yesterday` and `today` are dates, they always are `True` with `if statement`. And you read same text file for `yesterday` and `today` so your code ran wrong. Try this

```
import datetime

today = datetime.date.today()
yesterday = datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=-1)

try: # check if file exists
    with open(f"data_{yesterday}.txt", "r") as read_yesterday: # data_2022-07-22.txt file
        yesterday_data = read_yesterday.read()
        per_word = yesterday_data.split()
        yesterday_count = len(per_word)
except:
    yesterday_count = 0

try: # check if file exists
    with open(f"data_{today}.txt", "r") as read_today: # data_2022-07-23.txt file
        today_data = read_today.read()
        per_word = today_data.split()
        today_count = len(per_word)
except:
    today_count = 0
    
if today_count > yesterday_count:
    print("Good job! You wrote a lot!")
else:
    print("You should try to keep up!")
```

Comment: Well, it's supposed to read the same file. Do I need 2 files to read their word number counts to compare them or is there a way to only have one?

Comment: The best way is you need to save file name contains timestamp, ex yesterday file named  `data_2022-07-22.txt` and today file named `data_2022-07-23.txt`, so that content of each day will be separated and easy to compare to each other

Comment: Oh, alright. If that's the easiest way. Thanky you very much for you answer, by  the way!